# On load event for Leaflet proj4leaflet projected geoJSON layer

Tags: leaflet, geojson, proj, proj4js

Can't find proper event for vector layer like on "load", to be fired when this layer is fuly rendered. I add vector features to a layer in Leaflet using proj4leaflet from JSON object like this

```
   var geojsonLayer = L.Proj.geoJson(features, {
        'pointToLayer': function (feature, latlng) {
            return L.marker(latlng);
        }
    }).addTo(map);
```

And this methid does not work

```
geojsonLayer.on("load", function () {
        console.log(1);
    });
```

I need a loadend or renderend event for this layer. Is there any?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know there is no loadend-event included in Leaflet for GeoJSON-layers.

https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/issues/366

(Comment of mourner: "There is load event for all asynchronous layers (TileLayer and ImageOverlay). GeoJSON doesn't need that as it accepts already loaded JSON data, and loading logic happens externally." )

You could have a look at leaflet-ajax which will give you three events:

data:loading, data:progress and data:loaded.

https://github.com/calvinmetcalf/leaflet-ajax

This works nicely together with Leaflet.Spin:

https://github.com/makinacorpus/Leaflet.Spin

Here you can find a jsfiddle i set up:

http://jsfiddle.net/expedio/ea7esh0t/

Perhaps you can switch from L.Proj.geoJson to L.geoJson.ajax (reproject the data before you publish it?) or have a look at how these events were implemented so you could use them in L.Proj.geoJson,too.

Answer (score 0):

When using Leaflet-Ajax you can do:

```
//setup loading
geojsonLayer = new L.GeoJSON.AJAX(objJson, {style: style, onEachFeature: onEachFeature});
//wait to hit the function
geojsonLayer.on('data:loaded',function(e){
    alert("loaded");
}
```